# Django edit UserAdmin removes change password form from Admin Site

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='device', db_index=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

If I do this in the admin, it removes the "change password" form from the admin site:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [DeviceInline]

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Why? The `DeviceInline` is just a regular inline.

Comment: is the change password the only thing that is missing after adding inline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need your class to sub-class from UserAdmin so replace with this

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [DeviceInline]

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```